# pydev with scapy cant recognize imports

Tags: debugging, import, pydev, scapy

So i run into a problem today with scapy not recognizing my imports. This is not a version problem as i tried all possible python versions and both:

> from scapy import *
>
> from scapy.all import *

This problem is really annoying so any help will be much appreciated. At the moment i use python 2.5 with version 2.2 scapy.

Here is the code:

```
import logging
from scapy.layers.inet6 import IP
logging.getLogger("scapy.runtime").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
from scapy.all import  *

i = IP()
```

And here are the error messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Martinooos\Desktop\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_2.7.5.2013052819\pysrc\pydev_runfiles.py", line 432, in __get_module_from_str
    mod = __import__(modname)
  File "C:\Users\Martinooos\workspace\testing\test.py", line 7, in <module>
    from scapy.layers.inet6 import IP
  File "C:\Users\Martinooos\Desktop\scapy-2.2.0\scapy\layers\inet6.py", line 35, in <module>
    from scapy.layers.l2 import *
  File "C:\Users\Martinooos\Desktop\scapy-2.2.0\scapy\layers\l2.py", line 14, in <module>
    from scapy.ansmachine import *
  File "C:\Users\Martinooos\Desktop\scapy-2.2.0\scapy\ansmachine.py", line 14, in <module>
    from sendrecv import send,sendp,sniff
  File "C:\Users\Martinooos\Desktop\scapy-2.2.0\scapy\sendrecv.py", line 13, in <module>
    import arch
  File "C:\Users\Martinooos\Desktop\scapy-2.2.0\scapy\arch\__init__.py", line 79, in <module>
    from windows import *
  File "C:\Users\Martinooos\Desktop\scapy-2.2.0\scapy\arch\windows\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from scapy.sendrecv import srp1
ImportError: cannot import name srp1
```

Note: if i remove srp1 for example from the file another import error pops up so this goes for every single import. Since pydev recognizes the scapy folders i dont know what is going on.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Comment: noone can answer this?:(

Comment: Does the scapy command work independently? When you run it from command line and you have the interactive session?

Answer (score 1):

make sure to get the order right. the code below works fine.

```
import logging
from scapy.all import *
from scapy.layers.inet6 import IP
logging.getLogger("scapy.runtime").setLevel(logging.ERROR)

i = IP()
```

Comment: why does placing `from scapy.all import *` make everything work?